# clean activity data

Tags: android

I don't know the exact words to describe this, but my situation is this:
in my application, I give the users the options to choose which cities they want to display in google map, say there are 4 options, and the user clicks on two of them.  This is my listener method.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox option;
        int id = 1;
        while ((option = (CheckBox) thisActivity.findViewById(id)) != null) {
            if (option.isChecked()) {
                selected = selected + option.getText().toString() + ";";
            }
            id++;
        }
        Intent newintent = new Intent(thisActivity, ShowInMap.class);
        newintent.putExtra("SelectedCity", selected);
        // newintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        thisActivity.startActivity(newintent);
    }
```

I can successfully displayed those two selected cities on the map, but when I hit the back key and select one another city this time, the cities that were shown before were still on the map plus whatever I selected this time, and my Log says actually those three cities were sent to the map API. So my question, is there a way to clean those two selected cities and do a brand new selection. i.e only the city I selected the second time is on the map. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the variable `selected` is global, thus when you come back to the first activity to select the cities, new selected cities will be appended to the old `selected` String.

I suggest you clear the `selected` String first, every time before you start a new selection.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        selected="";//clear it
        CheckBox option;
        int id = 1;
        while ((option = (CheckBox) thisActivity.findViewById(id)) != null) {
            if (option.isChecked()) {
                selected = selected + option.getText().toString() + ";";
            }
            id++;
        }
        Intent newintent = new Intent(thisActivity, ShowInMap.class);
        newintent.putExtra("SelectedCity", selected);
        // newintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        thisActivity.startActivity(newintent);
    }
```